# Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

i currently programming a program in visual studio using the .net 3.5 framework and the microsoft interops to interact with the office products.
I have an issue with the app.config file. everytime i compile my solution, rebuilt or build it  a warning occurs in the error list witch says

Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.

when i double click this message visual studio tries to solve the problem, but with the next built the warning occurs again. i checked in the app.config file what visual studio tries to fix the problem and it seems, that it inserts these lines

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="office" publicKeyToken="71E9BCE111E9429C" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Vbe.Interop" publicKeyToken="71E9BCE111E9429C" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

i think that the bindingRedirect fails because of the version numbers but i can't edit them, because of the already "solve problem - build - problem occurs" thingy.

does anybody has any idea what might go wrong. i do not have any clue.

thanks for every idea!

Comment: You'd better enable verbose output of MSBuild and see if you can find out the conflicts, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/10/07/did-you-know-you-can-configure-the-msbuild-verbosity-in-the-output-window-329.aspx Diagnostics is the most common one to use when troubleshooting issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Jinx.  I'm on SO researching a similar issue with dependencies to Office assemblies.  In my case, I need to support older Office versions that I don't have installed on my DEV box (but are installed on a build server).

I decided to try the [MS Office Wrapper for .Net](http://www.codeplex.com/msofficefornet) open source project I discovered on one of the posts here.  It claims to support all versions of Office from 97 to 2007 (as long as you limit yourself to API calls that are available in the oldest version you need to remain compatible with).

Perhaps using that wrapper would solve/simplify your Office version dependency as well.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks you very much for mentioning the wrapper. The problem is, that my program is already completed. I don't want to rewrite all commands using this wrapper. But i will have a look at it and maybe for further versions migrate on this! thank you anyway!!

Comment: I'm in pretty much the same boat... program is done and considering whether to refactor.  I ended up writing a little parser that runs on the build machine that looks in the .csproj file for version references and changes them to the version installed on that build server.  If you don't have a separate server, a virtual PC works great as well.