# Xamarin Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to run Xamarin form app on Android but is is giving me the following error:

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent
>   assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it
>   and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following
>   binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application
>   configuration file:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.RegularExpressions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.IO" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Globalization" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.ObjectModel" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Extensions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.Debug" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq.Expressions" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Dynamic.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>
```

I have added this file in my config file but issue is still there. I don't know how can i fix this issue. Any one can help?

Comment: Ignore it, it is just a warning.

Comment: I clicked on it about a week and it was gone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly in xamarin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748065/found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-dependent-assembly-in-xam)

Comment: App is not running due to this warning.

Comment: @jimmgarr you are right i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I know its late for the response. There are quite a few solutions i read about in different articles.

Initially try to clean the builds and rebuild it.

I am not talking about build and deploy because in that case it might be hard to find out exactly when this problem is occurring. So build it from the build menu.

If it doesnt build and gives you error then check your android resource or assembly reference list for possible duplicate entries or assembly versions that might not be appropriate for your solution.

If you can build the project then try to deploy and if you find the same warning at this stage check your Emulator manager. As it happened in my case. Somehow my device definitions got corrupted and i had to recreate definitions. After that it was working normally. Also make sure to uninstall the app or clean your device if your definitions are fine.

I cant remember where i read it but somebody said often projects create similar dlls but different versions in the output directory and/or inside the device. That could create similar errors. So its always a wise to clean your project and device if your project throws any warning or error.

Also make sure you change the build error level to diagnostics for visual studio 2010 or over. Before vs 2010 detail option  should give you enough detail about any build errors.

Hope this will help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is working in debug, but will not publish to release mode then it might be the provisioning profile.  Mine was because my iOS Distrubution certificate did not match my iOS Distribution provisioning profile... once i had created the new profile that is assigned to the cert, then changing the iOS Bundle Signing to the new cert and prov profile everything worked.